# How to add more field columns using Inline Entity Form table display

Tags: entities

I was wondering if it is possible to have more columns in an Inline Entity Form table to show things like serial numbers and make/model after I input the Node ID. I was reading the answers from [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128669/how-to-show-fields-in-the-inline-entity-form-display-widget) but I am confused on how to make these work. But in the end I would like the table to look similar to this:
 [image]

For example, I would like to be able to input the existing Inventory number (node) and when I click "add" it will display the make/model and the serial number (if this is even possible). Which will then be saved as a Sales Order.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using ief_table_view_mode module or hook_inline_entity_form_table_fields_alter()

For more information see answers to a similar question: [How to show fields in the Inline Entity Form display widget?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128669/how-to-show-fields-in-the-inline-entity-form-display-widget?noredirect=1&lq=1)