# Inline Entity Form - is it possible to add field from child entity's taxonomy reference field

Tags: nodes, forms, taxonomy-terms, hooks, 9

I have the below structure on my Drupal 9 site:

```
Product content type
  -- field_product_integration (references contents of type Integration)
Integration content type
  -- field_product_feature (references terms from Features Taxonomy)
Features Taxonomy
  -- field_feature_category (Dropdown with three possible options)
```

On Manage Form for *field_product_integration* I have selected Inline Entity From Complex widget and hence I can select from Features listing provided by *field_product_feature* on Product add/edit form.

I need to also render *field_feature_category* in front of each Feature so that content editors can set *field_product_category* value for each selected Feature. I need this because each selected Feature can have one of the three possible values (*Yes/No/Unknown*). Creating hierarchy in Features taxonomy is not an option.

I checked the hooks provided by Inline Entity Form module and discovered that I can add fields from Integration Content type but unable to figure out if it is possible to add fields from Feature taxonomy (since it is referenced from child entity not from the parent entity itself).

[How to show fields in the Inline Entity Form display widget?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128669/how-to-show-fields-in-the-inline-entity-form-display-widget)

Sorry for the long question, I could not find a simpler way to explain my problem and I hope it's clear.